# Как отсортировать std::list комплексных чисел?

Tags: c++, ооп, list

При попытке сортировки через std::sort либо метод sort класса list выскакивает много ошибок, как я понял в связи с тем что нет перегруженных операторов сравнения.

Добавлено:
Компаратор

```
bool comp(std::complex<double> *a, std::complex<double>* b){
    double absa,absb;
    absa = sqrt(a->real()*a->real() + a->imag()*a->imag());
    absb = sqrt(b->real()*b->real() + b->imag()*b->imag());
    return absa > absb;
}
```

Вот как вызываю сортировку complex_lst.sort(comp);

Ошибка

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/list:64,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/list.tcc: In instantiation of ‘void std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::merge(std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&&, _StrictWeakOrdering) [with _StrictWeakOrdering = bool (*)(std::complex<double>*, std::complex<double>*); _Tp = std::complex<double>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::complex<double> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_list.h:1785:9:   required from ‘void std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::merge(std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>&, _StrictWeakOrdering) [with _StrictWeakOrdering = bool (*)(std::complex<double>*, std::complex<double>*); _Tp = std::complex<double>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::complex<double> >]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/list.tcc:635:20:   required from ‘void std::__cxx11::list<_Tp, _Alloc>::sort(_StrictWeakOrdering) [with _StrictWeakOrdering = bool (*)(std::complex<double>*, std::complex<double>*); _Tp = std::complex<double>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::complex<double> >]’
main.cpp:91:20:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/list.tcc:470:29: error: cannot convert ‘std::complex<double>’ to ‘std::complex<double>*’ in argument passing
  470 |                   if (__comp(*__first2, *__first1))
      |                       ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Где текст ошибки? И расскажите, какой порядок вы ожидаете увидеть.

Comment: Порядок по возрастанию

Comment: Текст ошибки сейчас закину,но там очень много всего

Comment: Что значит по возрастанию? Что "больше", `1` или `1i`, и почему?

Comment: У меня задание упорядочить список комплексных чисел по возрастанию

Comment: Вам надо сначала понять, какой порядок от вас хотят, перед тем, как садиться писать программу. `std::sort` не подойдет, для листа нужен `.sort()`, в который нужно передать свой компаратор (под тот порядок, который вы выберите).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: До этого не слышал о компараторах,попытался написать свой,но опять ошибка

Comment: Сравнивал модули комплексных чисел и по них пытаюсь сортировать

Comment: `cannot convert ‘std::complex<double>’ to ‘std::complex<double>*’` - Компаратор не должен принимать указатели, используйте `const std::complex<double> &`.

Comment: Работает,спасибо большое)

Comment: Можете добавить ответ я отмечу его как верный